# Member function called only on initialization of first instance of a class (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, member-functions

I have a member function for a base class that I only want to be called [once] on the initialization of the first instance of the class (whether it be a direct instance of the base class, or an inherited class). Basically, I want to avoid unnecessary function calls.

Comment: Have a look at [std::call_once](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once).

Comment: If you don't want to/cannot use c++11 or you think the solution proposed by juanchopanza is over the top, you can use a static bool flag indicating that the function was already run and not run it again.

Comment: I think the above two comments should be combined for an answer.:-)

Answer (score 7):

A thing that is done only done during the first time something happens is the initialization of function local statics during the first execution of the surrounding function. So how you could do it:

```
class X {
  static int firstInitFunc();

public:
  X() {
    static int onFirstCtorCall = firstInitFunc();
  }
};
```

Now the first time you create an `X`, `onFirstCtorCall` will be initialized (threadsafe), calling the function. Any following creation of `X` won't call that function again.

If you have multiple constructors on `X`, you'll still want only one call to the function. You can achieve that by either delegating to the constructor with the static variable or by using another static function:

## C++11:

```
class X {
  static int firstInitFunc();

public:
  X() {
    static auto onFirstCtorCall = firstInitFunc();
  }
  X(int) : X() // delegate to X()
  { /* ... */ }
};
```

## C++03:

```
class X {
  static int firstInitFunc();

  static void callFirstInit() {
    static int onFirstCtorCall = firstInitFunc();
  }

public:
  X() {
    callFirstInit();
  }
  X(int) {
    callFirstInit();
  }
};
```

**Update:** I'll pick up juanchopanza's comment and provide an example using `std::call_once`:

## C++11 using call_once

```
class X {
  static void firstInitFunc(); //see note to return types
  static std::once_flag firstInitFlag;

public:
  X() {
    std::call_once(firstInitFlag, firstInitFunc);
  }
  X(int) { 
    std::call_once(firstInitFlag, firstInitFunc);
  }
};
```

**Note to return types:** While in the case of function local statics' initialization used for the function call, that function *must* return a value, with wich the static will be initialized. In contrast, with `std::call_once` the function *may not* have a return type, because any returned value will not be evaluated.

Comment: +1 Thread-safety guaranteed by [stmt.dcl]/4; even though `std::run_once` is probably more idiomatic.

Comment: @DyP added a `std::run_once` solution

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

```
class C
{
private:
    static bool runOnce;

public:
    C()
    {
        if (!C::runOnce)
        { 
            C::runOnce = true;
            RunSth();
        }
    }
};

bool C::runOnce = false;
```

Comment: It doesn't even have to be a static data member of the class; it could also be a local static variable.

Comment: Is there a cleaner standard method perhaps? Some way to do it without a conditional check per instance and the added var? I know I am being a bit nit-picky about one byte... but I would like to learn how to write clean code.

Comment: @PhillipWeber "being a bit nit-picky about one byte" <-opposite directions-> clean code. There's a cleaner way though with C++11's `std::run_once`, although it also requires some storage.

Comment: @PhillipWeber See Arne's answer :)

Comment: @PhillipWeber The whole point is, that sometimes to keep the code clean, you have to use additional variables.